# add two virtual directoryor folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add two virtual directory/folder into the below url:

```
www.essartrainingacademy.com/php-mysql-training-in-chennai
```

I want to access like below using htaccess:

```
www.essartrainingacademy.com/training-courses/web-development/php-mysql-training-in-chennai
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/training-courses/web-development/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^/?training-courses/web-development/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

HTACESS I tried above, it is not working, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^training-courses/web-development/(php-mysql-training-in-chennai)/?$ /$1 [L,NC]
```